# Using CUDA Optionally on Linux

Tags: c, linux, cuda

I have an application, written in *C*, which runs on multiple platforms: Windows and various flavors of Unix. The two most important are Linux, then Windows.

One of the core algorithms could benefit from CUDA acceleration. However, everything must run normally if the system isn't CUDA-capable, (or the user doesn't specifically ask for GPGPU acceleration).

So, I need to make sure the application tries to load the CUDA libraries *only* under the right circumstances.

On Windows, the delay-load mechanism makes this fairly easy.

Is there a similarly easy mechanism to do this on Linux? Or do I have to go through the contortions involved with dlopen()?

Comment: you could statically link to the cuda libraries you need

Comment: Offtopic: the obvious alternative solution is to avoid CUDA and to use non-vendor-specific GPU acceleration, e.g. OpenCL, OpenMP or OpenGL compute shaders. These have their own drawbacks of course.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices, both perfectly valid:

1. As you note in your question, use `dlopen` to load dynamic libraries at runtime
2. Statically link the CUDA toolkit libraries into your application. NVIDIA have been shipping static versions of the toolkit libraries for linux for several major release cycles, and static linking is fully supported. The downside of this approach is application size.